# Audio recording using javascript in chrome extension bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, react-redux

I'm working on a project which needs ***audio recording*** functionality in a **chrome extension** . Any Javascript Code might help !

Comment: Hi Ajay, Please find yourself first, try it and then if you have issues in your code post here for us help you.

Comment: I actually couldn't find any APIs for this audio recording in an extension . Stuck up with the start itself , as none of the Chrome audio recording APIs are getting supported in extension

Comment: You have to give few things a try :) here is a simple JS https://github.com/bryanjenningz/record-audio  can be used to record audio, add it as content or background script?

Comment: Thank you @Ali .. That one was Working !

Comment: Glad it helped :) happy codding